# Scala warning - detects explicit references to FunctionN and TupleN that could be replaced with syntactic sugar

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, tuples

I have a following codes which always throws little warning on my intelliJ screen saying "Detects Explicit References to FunctionN and TupleN that could be replaced with syntactic sugar".

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
val data = Queue[Tuple2[String,String]]()
```

I don't understand what it means. How can you use syntactic sugar to simplify this line of code?

Comment: It isn't a Scala warning (you won't see it if you compile), it is IDEA's hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea can replace it. Clicking on the tuple, a menu pops up with a notification icon and other suggestions as shown here:

[image]

Here, simply select `"Replace Tuple[...] with (...)"`

Answer (score 5):

I guess just that `Tuple2[String, String]` has a synonym `(String, String)`, so `Queue[(String, String)]`.

I noticed that Eclipse offers to sweeten similar syntax in Java 8.